# How to create unique items in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

How to create unique items in RethinkDB?

In MongoDb I used `ensureIndex` for this, eg:

```
userCollection.ensureIndex({email:1},{unique:true},function(err, indexName){
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RethinkDB does not currently support uniqueness constraints on fields other than the primary key.

You could use an auxiliary table where the unique field is stored as the primary key in order to check for uniqueness in your application explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Essentially I just like to make one field unique. If I can solve that with the PrimaryKey it's ok for me!

Comment: Is this still the best solution? This was posted 3 years ago.

Comment: @chovy probably, I think they decided to nix unique secondary keys to avoid the kind of gotcha as in MongoDB allowing unique secondary keys but not guaranteeing their uniqueness across shards.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy alternative would be to use a secondary index. Thus not messing with auxiliary tables.

You can than do the check in your application with the `get_all` method (http://rethinkdb.com/api/#js:selecting_data-get_all).

Comment: The problem is that you cannot do this atomically. I.e. between the time where you check the secondary index and find that the key does not exist, and the time where you actually insert the document, somebody else could insert a document with the same key.

Comment: This link is broken. I don't mind if it's not gauranteed atomic -- but can you provide example code?